# Install new SSD drive and move /opt folder to it

Tags: centos, mount, ssd

I have a server with two SSDs in RAID1 configuration on a centos 7.9 machine. I am running out of space on the two SSDs, because of the RAID1 configuration and the size of the /opt folder. The RAID1 configuration has its' benefits.I will install a third SSD and I would like to move the /opt folder to it.

My understanding is that I would need to edit the /etc/fstab file and I think the modification should be something like this.

UUID=abcabcabdabd..abcd  /opt ext4 defaults 0 2

and then I would just have to move the folder over

Is the above understanding correct ?

Comment: `I will install a third SSD` not a third and fourth? I mean, it doesn't matter, just odd that you'd stop using RAID for the data that seems to be taking up most room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

- You attach the SSD to the system.
- Check in `dmesg` or using `lsblk` which device name is used.
- Then decide if you want to use partitioning. Note that you can use `ext4` on a raw block device, without partitioning, as well.
- After the filesystem is created (`mkfs.ext4`), you would rename `/opt` to `/oldopt`, edit the `/etc/fstab` file, put in the correct line (get the UUID from `blkid`). Add `,nofail` after `defaults` to prevent the system from going into maintenance mode when the SSD isn't present at boot time.
- Run `mount -a`, you should see the new and (almost) empty `/opt` present.
- Move over everything out of `/oldopt` to `/opt`.

If you run into SELinux troubles afterwards, it could be that the extended ACLs weren't moved over correctly (shouldn't happen). Then just run `restorecon -Rv /opt`.

Comment: Thanks for helpful list @Edward. I will give this a go

Comment: Hi @Edward, I have completed this sequence and it has been successful. However on two occasions I have still run out of memory, and it isn't clear how . I have been reading a bit about of inodes.Do I need to consider this when I create the file system ? The third drive is a 1TB drive. The two RAID1 SSDs are 512GB.